# How to replacte whole string or part of string from in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift, and stuck in-between development task.

I want to replace existing label string with another string or I want to replace part of string, also need to add this in my existing Swift in-built classes so I can further use it.

I'm very new Swift..please ignore any syntactical issues...

```
if str1.contains("ed"){
     str1.replacementObject(for: "MyNewString")
}
```

I'm getting error on this..."cannot convert value from string to expected argument type 'NSKeyedArchiver'"

I'll be more happy, if you could help me.

Comment: What is the value of `str1` and what do you want it to be after the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll guide you to implement this in the proper way, so you can reuse it further.

1. Add this extension outside you class

```swift
extension String {
    func replace(string:String, replacement:String) -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: string, with: replacement, options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
    }
}
```

2. Now you can use it as part of built-in functionality of String, as show below:

```swift
label1 = "MyOldString"
self.label1.text = self. label1.text?.replace(string: "Old", replacement: "New")

Output :- label1 = "MyNewString"
```

That's it!

Now you can use it anywhere in your project.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, now I'm able to replace my label text and able to use same in many another view-controllers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your'e Welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may use `replacingOccurrencesOf` function of String.

```
   let aString = "abcdef"
   let bString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "abc", with: "def")
   print(bString) // defdef
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me...your works but I'm not able to implement it in another class....@Ashish provide me perfect answer, thanks for your help.